# Key Hash Invalido

Tags: android, login, facebook, hash

Mi aplicación ya esta disponible en la playstore, pero por alguna razon el inicio de sesion con facebook no me funciona, me menciona que el key hash es invalido, cuando ya genere el hash para el modo producción

```
keytool.exe -exportcert -alias mi_alias -keystore C:\Users\mi-suario\Documents\AndroidProjects\Apks\mi_keystore.jks | "C:\Program Files\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl.exe" sha1 -binary | "C:\Program Files\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl.exe" base64
```

Me pide introducir la contraseña de almacén de claves e ingreso la contraseña del .jks y ese código que me da lo agrego a facebook developer en la seccion de "Android Hashes de clave"

Mis contraseñas estan correctas de eso no tengo duda

Answer (score 0):

El Keystore debe ser respaldado y guardado en un lugar seguro.

Si estas obteniendo el Hash de esta Keystore,

```
C:\Users\mi-suario\Documents\AndroidProjects\Apks\mi_keystore.jks
```

el Hash debes agregarlo en la configuración de Facebook en la sección `Hashes de clave`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si no permite iniciar sesión con Facebook puede ser por las siguientes causas:

> - El Hash que obtuviste no pertenece a la keystore con la cual firmaste originalmente tu aplicación.
> - El paquete de la aplicación que estas definiendo es incorrecto.
> - Asegura que la fecha y hora en tu dispositivo sea correcta.
> - Asegura tienes conexión en tu dispositivo.

Comment: El hash ya lo tengo agregado en la configuración  de Facebook y nada

Comment: @RaulMoguelZaldivar el Hash debe ser el obtenido a partir de la Keystore con la cual fue firmada tu aplicación para Google Play Store