# ¿Por que Facebook no reconose los hash de una maquina?

Tags: login, flutter, facebook, hash

### (Editado)

Debido a que no encuentro el problema ni explicación del por que este fallando el **hash**, pruebo haciendo el proceso de creación de **hash** en otra maquina.

Lo agrego a **Facebook developers** ejecuto la aplicación en **modo debug** y resulta que funciona perfectamente sin problemas.

- **¿Alguna razon por la que no funcione en mi maquina principal?**
- **¿Tengo que formatear mi maquina o reinstalar android studio?**

---

Anteriormente registre la app en **Facebook** para lo cual registre el **hash** generado con el siguiente código.

**Generar en modo debug**

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

pero al momento de probar el app me regresa el siguiente mensaje

> SERVER_ERROR: [code] 1349195 [message]: El hash de clave no coincide
>   con ninguno de los hashes de clave almacenados. Ve a
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android para
>   obtener más información. [extra]:

Nota: La app anteriormente funcionaba perfectamente con el **login de facebook** pero al haber otros problemas tuve que eliminar los anteriores hash por que la maquina ya no me genera el anterior si no uno nuevo

**¿hay algo que este haciendo mal?**

---

He probado crear un nuevo proyecto en **Facebook developer.** hacer toda la configuración nuevamente

1. Importe el SDK de Facebook
2. Agregue el paquete de mi proyecto
3. Agregue el **hash** generado de la siguiente manera.

**Ejemplo de como genere el hash**

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\Richard\.android\debug.keystore" | c:\Users\Richard\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | c:\Users\Richard\openssl-0.9.8k_X64\bin\openssl base64
```

Me pide contraseña del almacén, ingreso: **android**.
me muestra el siguiente **warning**

> Warning: El almacén de claves JKS utiliza un formato propietario. Se
>   recomienda migrar a PKCS12, que es un formato estándar del sector que
>   utiliza "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore
>   C:\Users\Richard.android\debug.keystore -destkeystore
>   C:\Users\Richard.android\debug.keystore -deststoretype pkcs12".

**¿Hay algo malo en como solicito el hash?**

4. Edito los recursos del **Manifest**
5. Agrego lo de **strings.xml.**

**Realizo la prueba con la aplicación y me regresa el mismo mensaje**

> SERVER_ERROR: [code] 1349195 [message]: El hash de clave no coincide
>   con ninguno de los hashes de clave almacenados. Ve a
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android para
>   obtener más información. [extra]:

**¿Que hago mal?**

Answer (score 1):

Cada vez que generas un nuevo `Keystore` mediante:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

**el HASH es diferente, por lo tanto ahora obten el HASH de este `Keystore` y [definelo en tu aplicación Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/apps/) el Hash para que tu aplicación pueda tener permisos.**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

para obtener el HASH revisa:

[keytool en windows no funciona para obtener hash para Facebook](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/151583/keytool-en-windows-no-funciona-para-obtener-hash-para-facebook)

Revisa rambién:

[Key Hash Invalido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/209372/key-hash-invalido)

Comment: Si ya seguí todos esos pasos, los agregue en el proyecto de facebook, pero en consola me sigue mandando lo mismo, de que el hash no concuerda con su almacén de hashes. agregue el has **debug** y el hash **release**

Comment: olvide mencionar que por errores, se tuvo que cambiar la key.jks que se usaba antes, siendo otra nueva, pero al estar en modo **debug** creo que no deberia afectar

Comment: @Richard importante que además del hash registrado también registres el paquete de la app.

Comment: Si, revise lo del paquete y lo agregue a **facebook**  seguí todos los pasos para la implementación del login. la primera ves que lo implemente funciono perfectamente, pero como se perdio la key.jks se penso en cambiarse el nombre del pakete para nueva subida a **playStore** igual se cambio en el proyecto de facebook, todo bien hasta ahi.. pero al regresar todo a como estaba antes (se recupero la **key.jks**) y cambiar el pakete con facebook ya no funciona

Comment: Entonces en la aplicación de Facebook revisa si el paquete es el que tienes actualmente.

Comment: Ya lo revise, de hecho edite mi pregunta, para mostrar los pasos que realizo, ya que cree un nuevo proyecto de **Facebook** y me manda el mismo error en consola de **Flutter**

Comment: Edite nuevamente mi pregunta, hice pruebas con otra maquina y el hash proporcionado funciona sin problemas, pero el que genera mi maquina no me lo acepta **Facebook developers**

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo he solucionado con el siguiente código, que debes colocarlo en el `MainActivity`, ahí en el LogCat, te dará la key hash valida, que debes colocar en la consola de Facebook developer.

```
 try {
     PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                       "{your-package-name}",                  //Insert your own package name.  
                        PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
     for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
         MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
         md.update(signature.toByteArray());
         Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
         }
      } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
              
      } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
              
      }
       ...
```

código kotlin:

```
 try {
        val info: PackageInfo? = packageManager.getPackageInfo(
            "{your-package-name}",  //Insert your own package name.
            PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES
        )
        if (info != null) {
            for (signature in info.signatures) {
                val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA")
                md.update(signature.toByteArray())
                Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT))
            }
        }
    } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
    } catch (e: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
    }
```

Aquí esta la documentación:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android/advanced

Comment: Muchas gracias por tu respuesta, pero debido a que es código `dart` tendría que revisar como colocar dicho código en `flutter`.

Answer (score 0):

en la aplicación puedes agregar un código extra para que te imprima en texto en pantalla el resultado de la operacion, te soltara en ese error el hash code que deberías utilizar para la aplicación por ejemplo si utilizas; void AuthCallback(ILoginResult result){} imprime result en el texto y busca después el hash cuando inicies sesión. lo hice en unity y funciono perfectamente

Comment: Esto no provee una respuesta a la pregunta.  En cuanto tengas suficiente [reputación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) podrás [comentar en cualquier publicación](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Es mejor [dar respuestas que no requieran clarificación de la persona que hizo la pregunta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/586/).

Comment: Hola @donat10. Bienvenido a **Stack Overflow**. Te invito realizar un [tour] para que conozca cómo funciona el sitio y gane tu primera medalla. Por otra parte, también puede consultar [¿Cómo escribo una buena respuesta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) o leer todo sobre «[respondiendo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/answering)»